# Using valgrind to measure cache misses

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, cpu, valgrind

I have a critical path which executes in one thread, pinned to a single core.

I am interested in identifying where cache misses are occurring. After looking around it seems valgrind's cachegrind tool would help me. However I have some questions regarding the tool's capabilities in this scenario:

1. How specific are the locations of cache misses provided? Does it output the variable name?
2. Can I profile just one thread?
3. Is it possible to profile specific parts of the code?
4. All the capabilities for measuring cache misses, do they equally-apply to TLB misses?
5. Can I use cachegrind with my release/optimised code?
6. I understand valgrind uses a virtual machine to sample. How accurate is this approach?

Question 1 is the most important.

Any help with command line arguments is most-appreciated.

Comment: I have an idea, why don't you go and read the documentation of [cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) instead of asking here?

Comment: @TonyTheLion you have an idea? Thats great.

Comment: Would be better to read the doc, and then ask multiple questions than one big question that cover everything you don't know.

Answer (score 10):

`cachegrind` can output both global and local informations concerning cache misses, and annotate at the line level (if the original program was compiled with debug information). For instance, the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  size_t n = (argc == 2 ) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 100;
  double* v = malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    v[i] = i;

  double s = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n ; ++i)
    s += v[i] * v[n - 1 - i];
  printf("%ld\n", s);
  free(v);
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with `gcc a.c -O2 -g -o a`
and run with `valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./a 10000000` outputs:

```
==11551== Cachegrind, a cache and branch-prediction profiler
==11551== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote et al.
==11551== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11551== Command: ./a 10000000
==11551== 
--11551-- warning: L3 cache found, using its data for the LL simulation.
80003072
==11551== 
==11551== I   refs:      150,166,282
==11551== I1  misses:            876
==11551== LLi misses:            870
==11551== I1  miss rate:        0.00%
==11551== LLi miss rate:        0.00%
==11551== 
==11551== D   refs:       30,055,919  (20,041,763 rd   + 10,014,156 wr)
==11551== D1  misses:      3,752,224  ( 2,501,671 rd   +  1,250,553 wr)
==11551== LLd misses:      3,654,291  ( 2,403,770 rd   +  1,250,521 wr)
==11551== D1  miss rate:        12.4% (      12.4%     +       12.4%  )
==11551== LLd miss rate:        12.1% (      11.9%     +       12.4%  )
==11551== 
==11551== LL refs:         3,753,100  ( 2,502,547 rd   +  1,250,553 wr)
==11551== LL misses:       3,655,161  ( 2,404,640 rd   +  1,250,521 wr)
==11551== LL miss rate:          2.0% (       1.4%     +       12.4%  )
```

The I1 miss rates tells us there was no instruction cache miss.

The D1 miss rates tells us there was a lot of cache L1 misses

The LL miss rates tells us there was some *L*ast *L*evel cache misses.

To get a more accurate view of the miss location, we can run `kcachegrind cachegrind.out.11549`, select the `L1 Data Read miss` and navigate in the application code, as shown by [image: this screenshot]

This should answer 1). I think the answer is no to 2) 3) and 4). It's yes for 5) if you compiled with debug info (without them, you'll get the global info, but not the per line info). As of 6) I'd say `valgrind` usually provides a very decent first approximation. Goig to `perf` is obviously more accurate !

Answer (score 0):

cachegrind isn't the only way to read the CPU performance counters.  Linux `perf`, and Intel VTune are widely used,  and various other frontends exist.

I haven't used cachegrind, just `perf`, but its output looks like it much be using the perf counters for recording cache misses with the instruction that caused them.

> How specific are the locations of cache misses provided? Does it output the variable name?

By machine-code address, i.e. a specific instruction.  Different frontends will do a better or worse job of helping you figure out what the load or store was actually doing without having to read asm and figure out which pointers the CPU had in which registers.  (They could record the address that was being used when the counter fired, to identify which cache line.)

Mapping from the instruction address back to the C++ source line isn't always obvious, in cases where the compiler did some serious loop transformations, or pulling a constant expression out of a loop after inlining a function that calculated it every call.  In general I'd recommend profiling optimized code.  If you're just looking for cache misses, the extra stack used for locals that optimized code would keep in registers probably isn't going to evict many lines from cache, and loading/storing varaibles to memory after every use just touches cache lines that are already hot.  Still, if you're looking at profiling output in general, noticing CPU-time hot spots as part of the process is only useful in optimized code.  This is esp. true for C++, where large amounts of template code is expected to inline and optimize away.

> Is it possible to profile specific parts of the code?

Yes, it should be possible to check the call chain when a perf counter triggers, and only count it if the current function was ultimately called by one of the functions you're interested in.  Or, enable counts when entering a function of interest.  IDK if cachegrind has a nice way to do this.

> All the capabilities for measuring cache misses, do they equally-apply to TLB misses?

Yup, there are hardware perf counters for TLB misses and page walks, as well as clock cycles, uops retired, etc.

Intel Sandybridge has 11 PMU counters, so you can sample 11 different things in one run with full accuracy (i.e. without time-sharing the counters).